# how to put inline image in automated mail from Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to send mail with an inline image instead of as an attachment through google sheet. Please help

the script is as below:

```
function emailSummary() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Hitesh")
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1T8QA_WsXQkZZGwmBSN13iPV7rM8xGG_GtYy6T1eug-c') 
    var gmail = 'hitesh.gtg@Gmail.com';
    var html =  '<png>'

    MailApp.sendEmail("hitesh.gtg@gmail.com", "sunject", "Dear Sir,\n\n Forwarding herewith Monthly Summaryw \n\n Regards \n Hitesh ", {
    //email address, subject, message

     name: 'Hitesh', //file name
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)] //file to attach
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [pass HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage) to the `.sendMail()` function. This link to the official documentation includes an example for inline images!

```
// This code fetches the Google and YouTube logos, inlines them in an email
// and sends the email
function inlineImage() {
  var googleLogoUrl = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
  var googleLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                         .fetch(googleLogoUrl)
                         .getBlob()
                         .setName("googleLogoBlob");

  //You can also get these images from your drive to attach them.

  var imgBlob = DriveApp.getFileById("<DRIVE_FILE_ID_OF_PICTURE>")
                     .getBlob()
                     .setName("imgBlob");


  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "recipient@example.com",
    subject: "Logos",
    htmlBody: "inline Google Logo<img src='cid:googleLogo'> images! <br>" +
              "img from drive: <img src='cid:driveImg'>"
    inlineImages:
      {
        googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,
        driveImg: imgBlob
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Emailing Images from your Google Drive

You can use the `htmlBody` parameter in `GmailApp.sendMail()`.  However, if you want to avoid having to store the image in a URL that is publicly accessible. You can do something like this.

This is a portion of my JavaScript:

```
 function sendImgMsg() {
    var fileId=$('#mediaSel').val();//This is the fileId where the image is store.  In my image converter script I keep all of this images in the same folder.
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(fObj){
      var msg=$('#emsg').val();//This is the contents of a textarea
      var hl='<p>' + msg + '</p><br /><strong>File Name:</strong> '+ fObj.name + '<img src="'+ fObj.uri +'" title="' + fObj.filetype + '" />';
      $('#email').css('display','none');
      google.script.run.sendImageMessage(hl);//This is the code that sends the email
    })
    .getSelectedFile(fileId);
  }
```

This is a portion of my html:

```
<div id="email">
   <textarea id="emsg" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
   <br /><input type="button" value="Send" onClick="sendImgMsg()" />
</div>
```

This is a portion of my code.gs:

```
function getSelectedFile(fileId){
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var dataURI=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var s=dataURI.split(',')[0];
  var mediaType=s.slice(s.indexOf(':')+1,s.indexOf('/'));
  var fileType=s.slice(s.indexOf('/')+1,s.indexOf(';'));
  var fObj={name:file.getName(),uri:dataURI ,type:mediaType,filetype:fileType};
  return fObj;
}

function sendImageMessage(hl) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail('recipient', 'ImageInAnEmail', null ,{htmlBody: hl});
}
```

This is the code that converts external images to imageURI's:

```
function convImageUrl(url){
  var blob=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var b64Url='data:' + blob.getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
  return b64Url;
}
```

The above is a part of a script that I use for converting images to imageURI's so that I can store and access them on my Google Drive.

Comment: This is interesting, but why not just `.getBlob()` on an image from Drive?

Comment: @Chris It's part of another script that I wrote and I just pieced the necessary sections together to share the information.  And it was something new to me so there is probably a better way to do it.