# Google apps script - UrlFetchApp to get image blob gets timeout error

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have created a script to automatically send a subscription-confirmation e-mail when a client submits a form.

In the e-mail, I embed an image that is fetched from my website with the `UrlFetchApp` class (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).

```
var logoUrl = "https://my.site.com/path/to/logo.png"
var logoBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(logoUrl).getBlob().setName("logo");
...
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: client.email,
    subject: "...",
    htmlBody: // html with reference to image like this:
              "<img src='cid:logo' width='107' height='160'/>"
    ,
    inlineImages: {
        logo: logoBlob,
    }
});
```

Since last week, this `UrlFetchApp` line causes a time-out error (error message in Dutch):

> Time-out: https://my.site.com/path/to/logo.png (regel 4, bestand 'inschrijvingsbevestiging', project 'inschrijvingsbevestiging')

This has worked before without any problem, the image file also is accessible from the given URL with a browser.

I'm new to javascript and google-apps-scripts so I have no idea where to start searching for a solution. The reference manual does not mention the time-out.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**EDIT** When I change the `logoUrl` path to some other image (I tried "https://www.google.be/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", the script works fine. So maybe there is a problem with my site?

**EDIT 2** Since the script works fine with another logo, the problem must lie on my webhost. I worked around the problem by putting the logo on my Drive, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: You have provided the bare minimum of code and it's not possible to reproduce the error. Rather than getting the image blob you could try embedding the image URL directly into the `img src` `"<img src='https://my.site.com/path/to/logo.png' width='107' height='160'/>"` There are obvious drawbacks to this method but it would at least work in the short term.

Comment: Another option is to host the image on your Drive and pull the image from there. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54716369/1691677

Comment: That's indeed what I have done (host on Drive). I can't imagine why my hosting provider would block such an UrlFetchApp request, but apparently that's what they do. Thanks!